# Looking for utility to look for identical blocks text within a *single* document

Tags: windows, software-rec, comparison, winmerge

I want to look for duplicate blocks of text within the *same* document.  Tools like WinMerge and Beyond Compare don't seem to do this.

Does anyone know of a utility that can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Simian](http://www.harukizaemon.com/simian/) does what you are looking for. It even allows you to define thresholds to catch smaller and smaller identical pieces of text. It isn't Open Source, but the license allows it be used free for evaluation and non-commercial use.